# Probability of 3 dice

Tags: probability, dice

Been looking through past exam papers and came across this question:

> Three fair dice are rolled. The probability that all three dice show $5$ is $1\over216$.

Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

This is true, since $\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{216}$.

Answer (score 0):

you can also look at it as a bernoulli experiment, with probability of success 1/6, probability of failure 5/6, 3 trials in total, and you want to know what is the probability that you get 3 sucesses. If you plug in these values in the binomial distribution, you should get 1/216